# How to check if remote process is executed - Long polling?

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using python 2.7.
I am using `paramiko` module to trigger a remote action. The process is long and typically runs for 15-20 minutes. At the end it generates a file locally.

I would not like to block a thread until the process is finished. Is there a way by which I can trigger another action once the file is generated?